# Wpf configuration service like global.asax

Tags: wpf, configuration, global-asax

[image]I am working on WPF Application.I am using Auto Mapper in WCF services.
 In My project I have different kind of layer like Service layer, Business Layer , Presentation Layer , I want to work on Service Layer that is (WCF).

In Auto Mapper there is creation of map

```
Mapper.Initialize(Item=> Item.CreateMap<Model.Person, PersonInfo>());
Mapper.Initialize(Item=> Item.CreateMap<Model.Bank, BankInfo>());
Mapper.Initialize(Item=> Item.CreateMap<Data, Model.DataInfo>());
```

When ever I call function at that every time it will call as per application perfomance.

I want to make as per global in application.That is **Create once in application and use as many time as they can**

How to Implement this concept of globalization at service layer in WPF application.

There is no concept of global.asax is WPF Application.then how to implement that concept of globalization of mapper initilization

Thank you.

Comment: you can use **App.xaml.cs**

Comment: But I have two solution One is business layer (WPF) and one is service layer (WCF) and my auto mapper creation is in Service Layer (WCF) and App.xaml file is in Business layer that (WPF)  how can I configure that ?

Comment: I am not able to calculate how it can be configure in app.xaml

Comment: Can you explain clearly? What and when you need to configure?

Comment: **App.xaml.cs**  has some virtual methods as **global.asax** has

Comment: you got solution?

Comment: Not , I just explain my question deeply

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5 hope this link will help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130070/discussion-between-manikandan-nagalakshmi-and-shivani).

Comment: you got solution?

Comment: No did't find solution yet , I had add my all mapper in app.xmal.cs but yet it is not create and give me error of configuration

Comment: Can you post your error?

Comment: I have add my error screen short

Comment: I don't know if I got what is your problem. But I have a structure similar to yours. 
My solution has N projects: Application layer(WPF), Common (my DTOs and other things), Domain (my entities), Persistence (NH stuff like repos), Service (WCF services) and Server( a cmd WCF server). My services understand only DTOs, so I receive DTOs and send back DTOs to my application. So, my automapper config is in my Application layer, to transform DTOs into Models for my MVVM.